# Workflow Rule to Check a Checkbox When the Purchase Date is bigger than 7 days

Tags: workflow

I need a workflow rule that will check a checkbox field called "Store Warranty" when the purchased date is less 7 days when compared to today's date. Example: If the customer bought a product 5 days ago, the checkbox will be checked, but the checkbox should be unchecked if the purchased date is bigger than 8 days when compared to today's date.

Comment: Wouldn't a formula field achieve the same purpose without using execution time? There's some precondition to force the workflow approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This one:

Create a New formula field with data type checkbox.

```
IF(purchased_date__c < Today()-7,False,True)
```